# Don't run function if field empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new here, and very new to Javascript and programming concepts in general. Part of the form I'm working on simlpy needs to calculate the difference between two prices. I do know float numbers are screwy, so I have that part figured out. And it calculates, and inputs it into field 3. The only thing I can't seem to figure out is making it so that if either field 1 or 2 is empty, the function doesn't run. It should only run when both fields are filled. Here's my example code:

```
<input type="text" id="1"> </input><br/>
<input type="text" id="2"> </input><br/>
<input type="text" id="3"> </input><br/>
<br/><br/><br/>
<p id="test"></p>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function emptyCheck(){
    if ($("#1") = ""){
        $("#3").val("");
    }
    else if ($("#2") = ""){
        $("#3").val("");
    } 
    else{
        rateDiff(); 
    }
}

function rateDiff(){
    var clientRate = $("#1").val() * 100;
    var agentRate = $("#2").val() * 100;
    var fareDiff = clientRate - agentRate;
    var fareDiffDec = fareDiff / 100;

    $("#3").val(fareDiffDec.toFixed(2));
}

$("#1").keyup(emptyCheck);
$("#2").keyup(emptyCheck);
</script>
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($("#1") = ""){
```

should be

```
 if ($("#1").val() == ""){
```

same for `$("#2") = ""`

`$("#1")` is a jquery element, not the value.
Also you put `=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#1") = "")
```

Should be

```
$("#1").val() == "")
```

One = is used to assign a value, while two == is to do a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "falsey" of JavaScript and the values:

```
function emptyCheck(){
    if (!$("#1").val() || !$("#2").val()){
        $("#3").val("");
    } 
    else{
        rateDiff(); 
    }
}
```

NOTE: you would be better parsing the numbers to handle alpha entry:

```
function emptyCheck() {
    if (!parseFloat($("#1").val()) || !parseFloat($("#2").val())) {
        $("#3").val("");
    } else {
        rateDiff();
    }
}

function rateDiff() {
    var clientRate = parseFloat($("#1").val()) * 100;
    var agentRate = parseFloat($("#2").val()) * 100;
    var fareDiff = clientRate - agentRate;
    var fareDiffDec = fareDiff / 100;

    $("#3").val(fareDiffDec.toFixed(2));
}

$("#1").keyup(emptyCheck);
$("#2").keyup(emptyCheck);
```

Comment: Note that you can decide how to handle "numbers" that parse such as 1e1 (which is 10) and 1e2 which is 100 etc.